# Chrome Extension - Unable to open pop-up page from context Manu

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I learning Chrome Extensions and trying build the following context menu that should open a pop-up with a link to wikipedia when a text is selected. Here is my code

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Wikit",
    "description": "Search Wikipedia on the go!",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons" : {
        "16":"icon16.png",
        "48":"icon48.png",
        "128":"icon128.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
        "persistent" : false
    },
    "permissions" : [
        "tabs",
        "contextMenus"
    ]
}
```

**eventPage.js**

```
var menuItem = {
    "id" : "wikit",
    "title" : "Wikit",
    "contexts" : [ "selection" ]
}
chrome.contextMenus.create(menuItem);

function fixedEncodeURI(str) {
    return encodeURI(str).replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']');
}

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(clickData) {
    if (clickData.menuItemId == "wikit" && clickData.selectionText) {
        var wikiUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"
                + fixedEncodeURI(clickData.selectionText);
        var createData = {
            "url" : wikiUrl,
            "type" : "popup",
            "top" : 5,
            "left" : 5,
            "width" : screen.availWidth / 2,
            "height" : screen.availHeight / 2
        };
        chrome.windows.create(createData, function() {
        });
    }
})
```

When I select a text and click Wikit, it is not opening the new pop-up/tab/page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's no such `type` as `"page"`. Always check the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-CreateType). Always check devtools - in this case for your background page on chrome://extensions and check the console for errors, also debug your code.

Comment: right, I even tried popup and that doesn't even work!

Comment: Make sure to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page.

Comment: Of course, I even tried removing and adding the extension back...it doesn't work!

Comment: Make sure to check chrome.runtime.lastError in chrome.contextMenus.create callback (to ignore it) because I see an error on subsequent runs.